# Liferay EE Theme Upgrading from LR 6.1 to LR6.2

Tags: liferay, upgrade, liferay-6, liferay-theme

We are moving from LR 6.1 to LR 6.2. 
The goal is to find the easiest way to upgrade our theme developed under 6.1.
is there any tool which helps to process this?
We Are Using Liferay 6.2 EE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no tool for themes - the architecture changed from "Liferay" to "Bootstrap", and with it several things that were natural in 6.1 - e.g. width percentage vs. span12. Given the additional features that you get in bootstrap (e.g. device-(width)-dependent layouts) it'd be really hard to do a mapping that would use any of the features in bootstrap.

There's such a tool for a [certain class of portlets](https://www.liferay.com/radio/-/asset_publisher/Q7Ic/blog/radio-liferay-episode-38-alberto-chaparro-on-the-migration-tool-for-portlets-version-6-1-to-6-2/1339770#portlet_101_INSTANCE_Q7Ic) though